# Keras model evaluate() and predict_classes() give contradicting results

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, computer-vision

I have been working for a while with VGG16 from Keras and after finetuning on my own 4 classes dataset, the training seems to be going well, the accuracy on training and validation sets increased and at the end, even the evaluation using `model.evaluate()` gave a good accuracy on testing data. I tried `confusion_matrix` and it also showed good classification results. In order to confirm, I tried to predict on images from my dataset using the following:

```
im = cv2.resize(frame,(image_size, image_size), interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)

#convert the image pixels to a numpy array
framer = img_to_array(im)             
image = framer.reshape((1, framer.shape[0], framer.shape[1], framer.shape[2]))

# prepare the image for the VGG model
image = preprocess_input(image)  

label = FLOW1_model.predict_classes(image, verbose=0)
```

I loaded flow frames for only 1 class (class 0) but about 30% only of the pictures were classified correctly, in another class (class 1) it was 50% correct classification. Given that the accuracy went above 85% when I trained, and also the confusion matrix showing very good results, I find this very abnormal. I looked at all possible causes online but couldn't find what went wrong... Is there a known issue that explains this difference in the results ?

Edit:

I basically load the Keras vgg without top, add my own classifier and compile the model like this:

```
# Compile the model method 2
sgd = SGD(lr=0.00001, decay = 1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
model.compile(optimizer=sgd, loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Comment: I'm not an expert at classification but I've worked with regression. Maybe you're using the wrong optimizer and loss algorithms? You could try show how you built your model.

Comment: I updated my question to include that part as well

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you cannot use the predict_classes() method in case of multi-class output.
Have you already tried with:

```
FLOW1_model.predict(image, verbose=0)
```

Comment: I never heard that predict_classes() cannot be used with multi-classes. But anyway, I tried again with         `label = FLOW1_model.predict(image, verbose=0)        
        lab = label.argmax(axis=-1)`
but it's still the same problem